# Can I set up a Javascript listener on the_content() link in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I am trying to test the call to action attached to the_content() on my self-hosted Wordpress. I know how to set an onclick _gaq.push in an HTML anchor but the php syntax of the_content() puzzles me:

```
<?php the_content("Continue reading &#9658;"); ?>
```

I assume that the Loop automatically generates the HTML anchor but how can I set up a GA listener on this link if it is not one in index.php?

Thanks in advance for any help you could offer!

Comment: Did you checked http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More ?

Comment: Yes but it mainly gives instruction on how to change the text displayed (that I am trying to test).

I feel that I would have to add/modify a function to function.php to track that link...

Comment: It also says you can add something like `the_content(<span class="something">text here</span>)`, so now you have a class selector, or an ID if you use that; I assume you can also use html5 `data-` properties